# Minecraft Skin Preview Problem

Tags: java, javascript, applet, minecraft

According to another question, you can view your skin with this code:

```
<applet code="net.minecraft.skintest.ModelPreviewApplet"
        archive="http://www.minecraft.net/skin/skintest.jar" codebase="."
        width="320" height="320">
    <param name="name" value="535" />
</applet>
```

Which works!

But does anyone knows how i can make a textbox and a button which puts the written text in the `value="535"` tag (replaces "535" with the text box input)?

Link to the other question: [Is there a web-embeddable skin preview application?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22075/is-there-a-web-embeddable-skin-preview-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your applet into the DOM at run-time like this:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<input type="text" value="" onchange="writeApp(this.value)">
<input type="button" value="go">

<script type="text/javascript">
function writeApp(pVal) {
     document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = '<applet  code="net.minecraft.skintest.ModelPreviewApplet"  archive="http://www.minecraft.net/skin/skintest.jar" codebase="."  width="320" height="320"><param name="name" value="'+pVal+'" /></applet>'   
}   
</script>
```

Strangely enough, the applet doen't seem to like values other than "525"

Answer (score 0):

That should be easy, but I don't think it will do what you want it to do.

I'm assuming you want to have a preview window with the texture preview, and allow users to type in new texture IDs, push the button, and see the preview right away.

Simply changing the value of the `param` after the page has loaded won't accomplish that.

When the button gets pushed, you'll need to remove the `applet` and re-create it, with the new param value in order for the changes to take effect.

Here's the code you asked for:

```
<applet
        code="net.minecraft.skintest.ModelPreviewApplet"
        archive="http://www.minecraft.net/skin/skintest.jar" codebase="."
        width="320"
        height="320">
    <param name="name" id="previewName" value="535" />
</applet>

<input type="text" id="newValue" />

<script>
document.getElementById('newValue').onblur = function(event) {
    // grab value
    var iVal = parseInt(this.value);
    if(!iVal && iVal !== 0) return;

    // update param
    document.getElementById('previewName').value = iVal;
    return true;
};
</script>
```

If you try that and it doesn't accomplish what you wanted, let me know and I can write the code that will do it.

Comment: I tried it and can you please add a button that loads that the new Textures when you type something new in? Because there isn't one now...